# Running eclipse on windows with linux jar and create an executable jar fir for linux

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, ubuntu-12.04, 32bit-64bit

I am using Eclipse Juno with windows 7 (64 bit) and i want to create an executable jar for my AWS-EC2 server (running ubuntu 12.04 32bit) with an external jar (AspriseOCL.jar).

My external jar is for linux (which will fit to my server).

Can i create this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

java is not OS based, so it wil work on any platform, 
java generates bytecode that is running inside the virtual machine, so if java is installed , it will work